# facebook-C#-sdk 5.0.3 beta - what is the replacement for FacebookClient.Session?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've read the change files and understand that FacebookApp is now FacebookClient. What I don't understand is how to tell whether the user is logged into Facebook like before (version 4.0 beta) where we simple checked fbApp.Session Is Nothing (VB.NET.) We could do this without instantiating an Authorizer class and checking IsAuthorized.

I'm using .NET 3.5, WebForms, VB and attempting to upgrade from beta 4 to beta 5.0.3

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session has been moved to the Authorizer class. Take a look at the code samples that come with the release for an idea as to how things work now.